# Django API: get authenticated user from request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The user is authenticated using allauth. I want to create a profile and set the authenticated user as the owner of the profile. How can I get the user?

Model class:

```
from django.db import models
from allauth.utils import get_user_model
from courses.models import Course

class Profile(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)

    def get_courses_items(self):
        return self.courses.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.username
```

Views:

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

from profiles.models import Profile
from .serializers import ProfileSerializer

class ProfileCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user from the request with `request.user`. Then probably you should override the `def create` method of the `CreateAPIView` to use that user and create the object.

Answer (score 0):

set your user model in the  settings file (base.py) and import it

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User' #(format is module.user model name)


from django.conf import settings


user = models. OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

method 2

Override the get_create method of the ProfileView. Every authenticated request has a `request.user` object in it which represents the user making the request. To get the user's id with this you just run `request.user.id`

```
class ProfileCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer



    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        # create the profile and save it
        ...
```

in your serializers you can also get the current user this way

```
from rest_framework.serializers import CurrentUserDefault, PrimaryKeyRelatedField

class ProfileModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
    ...
```

I don't know how the remainder of your setup is but any or a combination of these works